# Output statement

Tags: java, decimal, output

I am looking for the repeating sequence in a decimal output and I can't get it to output correctly :/ ( I may be responding to answers a little late. Sorry)

e.g .

N = 1, D = 7

1 / 7 = 0.142857142857142857...

output = 0.(142857)

or

N = 45, D = 56

45 / 56 = .803571428571428571428

output = .803(871428)

Here is my code below:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class RepeatingSequence{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter N,D: ");
    double numerator = in.nextInt();
    double denominator = in.nextInt();

    double quotient = numerator / denominator;
    String number = "" + quotient;
    char n = number.charAt(0);
    int j = 2;
    int z = 0;
    String output = "";
    char[] index = new char[100];

    for ( int i = 3; (i < number.length()) && (number.charAt(j) >= number.charAt(i) || (number.charAt(j) <= number.charAt(i))); i++ ){
        index[z] = number.charAt(z);
        index[j] = number.charAt(j);
        index[i] = number.charAt(i);
        if ( index[i] != index[z] ){
        System.out.print("(" + index[i] + ")");
        }
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: what do you thin the for should do? i=3? I would fill your array before the search loop (or use string.charAt only)

Comment: This is a much harder problem than it may first appear.  Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: i = 3 would determine the char at (2)? I think that was the purpose I meant to do. - eckes

@ajb - It's not really mandatory to pass this. But I need it to get extra credits.

Comment: Note that you are not going to really get correct answers with this approach.  For one thing, `number` will be only an approximation to 15 decimal places, because of how floating-point numbers are represented.    If your goal is to look for repeating sequences in `number` and hope that's close enough, we might be able to help you with that.  But really getting the right answer requires a good amount of number theory.

Comment: For `45/56`, `number` will be `"0.8035714285714286"`.  That `6` on the end is because the value is rounded up (from `....57`).  That could easily screw up any algorithm that looks at `number` for repeating sequences.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this is #26 from Project Euler. You should take a look at Eli Bandersky's page on this: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/02/25/project-euler-problem-26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determining the mathematically correct answer is not easy and requires some number theory.  (I've actually done stuff like this, and I had to look up things like Euler's totient function and primitive roots.)  Converting a `double` to a `String` is problematic because numbers like 1/7 cannot be represented exactly in a `double`, and the resulting string could involve some rounding.

An alternative that will work on the two examples you give (but won't work in every case) is to use the `number` you have, and then in the decimal fraction part, find a substring *S* such that *S* occurs right next to itself in `number`.  I'm not going to give you the code, of course, but the general plan would be something like this:

Use the `indexOf` method of `Strings` to find the `.`.  If this is at index *N*, then start at *N+1*.

Starting at `startIndex` = *N+1*, try this for `i = 1, 2, 3, ...` until you run off the end of `number`:

```
if (number.substring(startIndex, startIndex + i).equals(number.substring(startIndex + i, startIndex + 2*i))) {
```

If these two substrings are equal, then you can assume you have a repeating decimal.  You would then output the substring of `number` from the beginning to `startIndex`, then `(`, then `number.substring(startIndex, startIndex + i)`, then `)`.

If `i` gets so large that you run off the end of the string, then increase `startIndex` by 1, and start over again with `i = 1`.

**EDIT:** If your extra-credit assignment really is to solve Project Euler Problem 26 (as @ChthonicProject mentioned in his comment), then I'd go with the number-theory solution, rather than the approximate solution.  It was just hard for me that this would be given as a class assignment, even for extra credit, unless this is a rather advanced class.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir for the hints(/tips?). And yeah, it was an extra activity in our book and our instructor told us that we could answer it for extra credits. And its not an advanced class i'm afraid

Comment: Is this correct though?
for ( i = 0; i <= number.length(); i++ )

if ( i == number.indexOf(".") )

Comment: @RodGalangco This is redundant.  `number.indexOf(".")` will search the string looking for `.`; therefore you don't need another loop to search for it again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have been busy with my studies (finals week). Sadly, I have not been able to submit this but it's okay. I'd try to figure the code out in my free time. Thank you very much for the help ajb :)